# How can I print particular table from a web page?

Tags: html

I need to print a arithmetic operators table in same table format alignment as http://u3schools.com/tutorial/php/php_operators.jsp. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a css file that will just output the table you want when it goes to the printer?

I am assuming that the table you want to print is on your webpage, and that you are not trying to print this from another page, btw.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/